# How can I use a gem locally without forcing it on collaborators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rubygems

I'm working on a collaborative Rails project and I'd like to make use of Thoughtbot's excellent [vim-rspec](https://github.com/thoughtbot/vim-rspec) gem in my own development environment without polluting the project's Gemfile (not many of the collaborators use Vim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vim.rspec recommends it is installed as a vundle.  It isn't a gem but more of a plugin.

There are instructions to install vundle on the [homepage](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim).  If you install it locally outside of the rails project it won't affect your collaborators.

Comment: Right you are! I guess I assumed that since rspec-rails is a gem, and is included in the project's Gemfile... Actually, looking back, I don't know why I thought this would be an issue; just got my wires crossed I guess.