# Use a gem in rails locally without forcing it on collaborators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use [Rails Panel](https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel) gem without adding code to version control and forcing it on other collaborator.

I could do a `gem install rails_panel`, but I still need to load it when my application starts.

NB: The answer to this thread is not relevant to my question because the Rails Panel gem needs to be "required". [How can I use a gem locally without forcing it on collaborators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449477/how-can-i-use-a-gem-locally-without-forcing-it-on-collaborators)

Comment: here is a more simpler way you can do: https://gist.github.com/manuwell/faafcf15eba892d9f5839697f6b24511

Comment: @wjsantos It doesn't answer the question since I need to modify the gemfile (which I can't do without the approval of the team). Could you re-open the question? I think it might interest other people if it has been upvoted.

Comment: Uhmmm ... I understood that others don't want to use and inserting into development group without requiring could be a help. If you don't want to change the Gemfile, the solution you find fits very well

Comment: @manuwell Yes, my team doesn't want to use this gem so I can't modify the gemfile.  The solution, in the other thread doesn't work because I need to load the gem when the application starts.