# Use a gem locally in a rails app without modifying the Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rubygems, bundler

I need to locally use a gem ([Rails Panel](https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel)) in a rails app **without adding code** to `git`.

The reason I cannot modify code in version control is because my team has a very strict policy on adding new gems. It's not ideal but I can exclude files from version control if I have to.

I tried the following solution but it doesn't work:

1. Run `gem install meta_request`
2. Modify the file `bin/rails` with the following code:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# original code [...]

gems = %w[meta_request]
gem_home = ENV['GEM_HOME']
gem_dir = Dir["#{gem_home}/gems/*/lib"]
gems.each do |gem|
  gem_path = gem_dir.select { |r| r.include?(gem) }
  $LOAD_PATH.append(*gem_path)
  require gem
end
```

3. Add `bin/rails` to `.git/info/exclude`

NB: The answer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449477/how-can-i-use-a-gem-locally-without-forcing-it-on-collaborators) doesn't work in this case because the gem needs to be "required". How can I use a gem locally without forcing it on collaborators?

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1 (easy to understand but not generic)**

A quick solution without modifying the load path.

Step 1, open a terminal and run this command to get full path of the gem that you want to use locally:

```
gem which GEM_NAME
```

Step 2, create an initializer file `local_dependencies.rb` in `config/initializers/` and require your gem(s) in the file like this:

```
# file: config/initializers/local_dependencies.rb

require 'GEM_FULL_PATH'
```

Step 3, edit `.git/info/exclude` and exclude `local_dependencies.rb` file:

```
# file: .git/info/exclude

config/initializers/local_dependencies.rb
```

All done!

**Solution 2**

This is a more generic solution, although both solutions are bypassing bundler but the advantage is that you don't have to update the Gemfile.

Create an initializer file `local_dependencies.rb` in `config/initializers/` and add this code:

```
gems = {
  'meta_request' => '0.7.2',
}
gem_home = ENV['GEM_HOME']
gems.each do |gem_name, version|
  gem_path = "#{gem_home}/gems/#{gem_name}-#{version}/lib"

  raise "GemNotFound: name: #{gem_name}, version: #{version}" unless File.directory?(gem_path)

  $LOAD_PATH << gem_path
  require gem_name
end
```

Edit `.git/info/exclude` and exclude `local_dependencies.rb` file:

```
# file: .git/info/exclude

config/initializers/local_dependencies.rb
```

All done!

Comment: I like this solution, but you are bypassing bundler, and this can lead to incompatible versions.

Comment: I like the fact of using an initializer instead of modifying bin/rails but I'm not fond of hardcoding the full path because I used rbenv and we "frequently" update the ruby version. I'll try to do a mix of your solution and mine.

Comment: @LesNightingill, yes this is bypassing bundler, you are right, but the advantage is that you don't have to update the Gemfile. Also I've updated the answer to include a more generic solution that will resolve the multiple versions issue.

Comment: @LéonardHenriquez, can you please check if the 2nd solution solves your problem?

Comment: @LesNightingill, i agree that requiring gems this way without using the power of bundler can lead to incompatible versions.

Comment: @AbubakarAzeem, you new solution doesn't work as it is because the initializers from the gem (cf [the rails doc](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Railtie.html)) are not run. I tried to add `MetaRequest::Railtie.run_initializers(Rails.application)` but it still doesn't work. To make it work I had to move the code into `config/boot.rb` but it's not ideal

Comment: Actually I notice that I had `gem 'meta_request', require: false` in my gem file, and it doesn't work at all when I remove it

Answer (score 0):

You can always define groups like development or test which won't effect anything in production so you can push them to git without worrying about the code.

```
group :development do 
   gem 'gem-name'
end
```

or

```
group :test do
   gem 'gem-name'
end
```

Comment: I can't modify the Gemfile for everybody because the review won't get accepted. I could mkae the change only locally and add the Gemfile to `.git/info/exclude` but it would be very tedious to keep up with the frequent changes...

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing magic about the environment names, ('development', 'production', 'test'). So you can define an environment that you alone use, like 'lh_development'.

To support this you will need a file config/environments/lh_development.rb, which would essentially be a duplicate of config/environments/development.rb. And in your Gemfile, you can define the gems included in the :lh_development group...

```rb
group :lh_development do
  # here list all the same gems that are included in the :development group
  gem 'meta-request'
end
```

then you will start your server on your dev machine with

```sh
RAILS_ENV=lh_development rails s
```

of course, you would be ill-advised to test your code with your special gem included, b/c your test build should be the same as the other devs and the production build.

I suppose this does not strictly meet your requirement to not modify Gemfile, but it does so in a way that doesn't affect other devs or test/production env. So maybe your team can live with it?

Comment: I can't modify the Gemfile for everybody because the review won't get accepted. I could mkae the change only locally and add the Gemfile to `.git/info/exclude` but it would be very tedious to keep up with the frequent changes...

Comment: you can keep the customised Gemfile and the custom config/environments/lh_development.rb in a git branch on your dev machine. But management of your local master branch will still be a bit messy.